# SQL Filling In Values From A Second Table

Tags: sql, performance, teradata

I came up with this query to fill in a missing field from a second table using a subquery.
I can not modify the *original* table

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN original.target_field IS NULL THEN  
  (SELECT fill_in.target_field FROM second.table fill_in 
   WHERE original.id = fill_in.id)  
ELSE  
  original.target_field END AS myField
FROM 
  primary.table original
```

I was wondering if I was missing something and if there was a more performant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` instead of correlated subquery:

```
SELECT COALESCE(original.target_field,fill_in.target_field) AS myField
FROM primary.table original
LEFT JOIN second.table fill_in 
  ON original.id = fill_in.id
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always worth testing different methods.  But your query should be fine with an appropriate index.

I would write it as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN o.target_field IS NULL  
             THEN (SELECT f.target_field
                   FROM second.table f 
                   WHERE o.id = f.id
                  )  
             ELSE o.target_field
        END) AS myField
FROM primary.table o;
```

You want an index on `second.table(id, target_field)`.  You would want the same index for the `LEFT JOIN` version.